# Composite key syntax in Boost MultiIndex

Tags: c++, boost

Even after studying the [examples](http://www.ccp4.ac.uk/ccp4bin/viewcvs/*checkout*/cctbx/cctbx_sources/boost/libs/multi_index/doc/advanced_topics.html#composite_keys), I'm having trouble figuring out how to extract ranges using a composite key on a MultiIndex container.

```
typedef multi_index_container<
  boost::shared_ptr< Host >,
  indexed_by< 
    hashed_unique< const_mem_fun<Host,int,&Host::getID> >, // ID index
    ordered_non_unique< const_mem_fun<Host,int,&Host::getAgeInY> >, // Age index
    ordered_non_unique< const_mem_fun<Host,int,&Host::getHousehold> >, // Household index
    ordered_non_unique< // Age & eligibility status index
      composite_key<
         Host,
        const_mem_fun<Host,int,&Host::getAgeInY>,
        const_mem_fun<Host,bool,&Host::isPaired>
        >
       >
    > // end indexed_by
  > HostContainer;
```

My goal is to get an iterator pointing to the first of the subset of elements in `HostContainer hmap` that has age `partnerAge` and returns `false` to `Host::isPaired()`:

```
  std::pair< hmap::iterator,hmap::iterator > pit = hmap.equal_range(boost::make_tuple( partnerAge, false ) );
```

I think this is very wrong.

1. How/Where do I specify the iterator index (which should be 3 for age & eligibility)? I will include other composite keys in the future.
2. What exactly are the two iterators in `std::pair`? (I'm copying syntax from an example that I don't understand.)

   I would ideally use `std::count` to calculate the number of elements of age `partnerAge` that are eligible (return `false` to `Host::isPaired()`). What is the syntax for extracting the sorted index that meets these requirements?

I'm obviously still learning C++ syntax. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get access to N-th index you could use function `get` as follows:

```
std::pair< hmap::nth_index<3>::type::const_iterator,
           hmap::nth_index<3>::type::const_iterator > pit = 
  hmap.get<3>().equal_range(boost::make_tuple( partnerAge, false ) );
```

`equal_range` returns pair of iterators of N-th index. You will get range of elements that are satisfy the specified condition since your composite key is not unique. To iterate through that range you could use loop from the first iterator to the second iterator.

Consider using named indexes to use them as `get<index_name>()`, because specifying actual number is not very readable.

`count` has syntax similar to `equal_range`:

```
size_t cnt = hmap.get<3>().count(boost::make_tuple( partnerAge, false ) );
```

Comment: Thanks, Kirill. I am using typedefs to simplify the indices but will incorporate tags too. Is the correct syntax to access the starting iterator in the range ...firstItr = pit->first? (That assignment isn't working. I'd like that iterator so I can increment it a random number of times to access a random Host that meets the composite key's criteria.)

Comment: (The random number of times that firstItr is incremented will obviously be less than count so that it stays in range.)